# How to make a section of an image a clickable link

Tags: asp.net, html, hyperlink

I have a banner on web page, and part of the image there is a graphic of a button box. How do I make just the part where the button is a clickable link such as a href? You can see a sample image below.

[image: sample banner image with button graphic]

In the banner image there is a "Join Now, Its Free" Button graphic.  I want to add a link on this box, so when users click on this box on the banner, then it will open the next page.  I want to know how I can add a link on just this button.  I don't want to add the `<button>` tag to it; I just want to add a link based on the area of the "Join Now, Its Free" Button graphic.  Anybody have any ideas on how I can add a link on this part of the image area without using the `<button>` tag.

```
 <div class="flexslider">

                <ul class="slides" runat="server" id="Ul">                             
                    <li class="flex-active-slide" style="background: url(&quot;images/slider-bg-1.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll 50% 0px transparent;                                               width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: list-item;">

                      <div class="container">

                        <div class="sixteen columns contain"></div>   

                          <img runat="server" id="imgSlide1" style="top: 1px; right: 
       -19px; opacity: 1;" class="item" 
           src="images/slider1.png"            data-topimage="7%">
                           <a href="#" style="display:block; background:#00F; width:356px; height:66px; position:absolute; left:1px; top:-19px; left: 162px; top: 279px;"></a>      


                      </div>   


                  </li>
                </ul>

            </div>

            <ul class="flex-direction-nav">

                <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a></li>
                <li><a class="flex-next" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a></li>
            </ul>           

        </div>
```

Thank You

Comment: Make it a separate `<img>`. Wrap it with `<a href="...">`.

Comment: I know this it this a banner it will make a hyperlink on all banner i want link on only that Joun Now, Its Free Button box this.

Comment: Repeating the question won't change my recommendation. There's no apparent reason that that button graphic should form part of the rest of the image.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you don't want to make the button a separate image, you can use the `<area>` tag.  This is done by using html similar to this:

```
<img src="imgsrc" width="imgwidth" height="imgheight" alt="alttext" usemap="#mapname">

<map name="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" coords="see note 1" href="link" alt="alttext">
</map>
```

Note 1: The `coords=" "` attribute must be formatted in this way: `coords="x1,y1,x2,y2"` where:

```
x1=top left X coordinate
y1=top left Y coordinate
x2=bottom right X coordinate
y2=bottom right Y coordinate
```

Note 2: The `usemap="#mapname"` attribute must include the `#`.

**EDIT:**

I looked at your code and added in the `<map>` and `<area>` tags where they should be.  I also commented out some parts that were either overlapping the image or seemed there for no use.

```
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides" runat="server" id="Ul">                             
        <li class="flex-active-slide" style="background: url(&quot;images/slider-bg-1.jpg&quot;) no-repeat scroll 50% 0px transparent; width: 100%; float: left; margin-right: -100%; position: relative; display: list-item;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="sixteen columns contain"></div>   
                <img runat="server" id="imgSlide1" style="top: 1px; right: -19px; opacity: 1;" class="item" src="./test.png" data-topimage="7%" height="358" width="728" usemap="#imgmap" />
                <map name="imgmap">
                    <area shape="rect" coords="48,341,294,275" href="http://www.example.com/">
                </map>
                <!--<a href="#" style="display:block; background:#00F; width:356px; height:66px; position:absolute; left:1px; top:-19px; left: 162px; top: 279px;"></a>-->
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!-- <ul class="flex-direction-nav">
    <li><a class="flex-prev" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-left"></i></a></li>
    <li><a class="flex-next" href="#"><i class="icon-angle-right"></i></a></li>
</ul> -->
```

**Notes:**

1. The `coord="48,341,294,275"` is in reference to your screenshot you posted.
2. The `src="./test.png"` is the location and name of the screenshot you posted on my computer.
3. The `href="http://www.example.com/"` is an example link.

Comment: How can i check location is right going on image how can i check this

Comment: First I have a question: is this button in the bottom left of your image?

Comment: Ok then the X1 would equal 0 and the Y1 would equal 0.  Now use an image editor and measure from the bottom left corner to the bottom right corner; this will give you X2.  Then measure from X2 to the top right corner of your button; this will give you Y2.  Now put the `coord` attribute into your `<area>` tag as follows: `coord="0,0,X2,Y2"`.

Comment: please check detail in add in description that is now working in tags which i add in description

Comment: Are you asking me where you should add in the `<area>` tag and `<map>` tag?  I don't exactly understand what you mean, as you have no punctuation in your comment.

Comment: yes i want to know where i can add it as you asked i add like that but not working you can check i add a code which im using in slider

Comment: @Vikram please check my edit.  It should answer your question.

Comment: @Burn_E99 Nice solution! Please can you tell me how to ensure that LINK won't be distorted on different screen sizes (or different browsers/devices etc) ?

Comment: @Dusht I am not exactly sure how that works, but I am assuming it locks onto the image, and not the location on the screen.  If the webpage has auto-resizing images, then it may get messed up.

Comment: And to get map co-ordinates, use this site - http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/ (not associated with it in any way, just used it)

Comment: To get circle or polygon coordinates, you can go to https://www.image-map.net/ . And if you're concerned about responsiveness, try https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer
(not related, I'm just discovering and sharing)

Answer (score 16):

You can auto generate Image map from this website for selected area of image. https://www.image-map.net/

Easiest way to execute!

Comment: Thank you so much, you saved me hours of figuring out coordinates :D

Comment: This tool is amazing

Answer (score 8):

by creating an absolute-positioned link inside relative-positioned div..
You need set the link width & height as button dimensions, and left&top coordinates for the left-top corner of button within the wrapping div.

```
<div style="position:relative">
 <img src="" width="??" height="??" />
 <a href="#" style="display:block; width:247px; height:66px; position:absolute; left: 48px; top: 275px;"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check update description there link didnt getting on box

Comment: Excellent answer. This has the benefit of all the style that can happen on a <a> tag, but the drawback of not being able to be an arbitrary <area> (shape poly).

Comment: Nice one. Doesn't seem to work on top of an object (svg) though.

Comment: @Christian It seems to work, maybe post your code in a separate question

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make the "button image" as a separate image.
Then place it over the main image (using "style="position: absolute;".
Assign the URL link to "button image".
and smile :)