# How can we lock the <area> tag on a image so that changing screen resolution doesn't change the clickable target area?

Tags: css, html

In continuation to the earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link), I want to know how can we lock the  tag on a image so that changing screen resolution doesn't change the clickable target area?

```html
<area shape="rect" coords="48,341,294,275" href="http://www.lego.com/en-us/">
```

The above coordinates are decided based on a particular screen size and browser and are subject to change.

Is there any facility in `HTML5`?

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

Comment: The question's about `<area>` element, not `<textarea>` :)