# Hyper-linking parts of an image

Tags: html, css

hi so i'm trying to hyperlink parts of an image to different web pages.

The image is a map, so clicking on different sections, should take it to the relevant web page. 
I would like to use only HTML5 and CSS3.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Image link is below.

[Floor Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gecp.jpg)

Comment: You can use [image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) to accomplish this

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

refer that link.

Comment: thanks. is there a way to figure out the exact coordinates? i don't really understand it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a section of an image a clickable link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link)

Comment: As far as I know, you need to figure out the coordinates manually, by using paint or something, with relative to your image position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, you can use [image maps](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) for this. There are many online image map generators you can use to define the coordinates(such as [image-maps.com](http://www.image-maps.com/)). Here's an example using the image you provided:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Gecp.jpg" usemap="#linkmap" />

<map name="linkmap">
  <area  alt="board-games" title="Board Games" href="boardgames.html" shape="rect" coords="17,86,188,214" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
  <area  alt="lego-models" title="Lego Models" href="lego-models.html" shape="rect" coords="130,256,367,372" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
  <area  alt="playing-cards" title="Playing Cards" href="playing-cards.html" shape="rect" coords="261,110,377,197" style="outline:none;" target="_self"     />
</map>
```

Comment: that is great! thanks a lot. i thought i'd have to include extra blank images, place them over the areas and hyperlink them.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!