# After importing the image into the template node, i want to select only a certain part of the image as the coordinate and make it a button

Tags: html

After importing the [image] into the template node, i want to select only a certain part of the image as the coordinate and make it a button.

i am `node-red` beginner please help me

Comment: This is not really a node-red question... it's more of an HTML question. The [html `<area>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link) is one way to do it.

Comment: As @SteveR said, this is not a Node-RED question, I'm going to edit the tags to something more appropriate. You should also edit the question to show what you have put in the template node